# timeout error on salesforce refresh token connected app via apps script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, salesforce, refresh-token

I have a Salesforce connected app that runs on Google Apps Script. 
It was working and running, but I reduced the trigger to 1x a day and it stopped due to session timeout.

When I try to run my refreshToken I get a session timeout, but when I log the saved session parameters I can see the refresh_token. I have been pouring through all the forums, but cannot find the answer. I have the right oAuth2 scopes (I think)...

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

```
// This function can be run periodically to replace an expired access token.  More details: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en_US
function refreshToken() {
  var props = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var uProps = JSON.parse(props.getProperties()['oauth2.salesforce']);  // assumes the service's name is "salesforce" (set when service was created)
  Logger.log(uProps.refresh_token);
  var sProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var clientId = sProps.getProperty('sfConsumerKey');
  var clientSecret = sProps.getProperty('sfConsumerSecret');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&refresh_token=' + uProps.refresh_token, {method: 'POST'});
  var nuProps = JSON.parse(response);
  uProps.signature = nuProps.signature;
  uProps.access_token = nuProps.access_token;
  uProps.issued_at = nuProps.issued_at;
  props.setProperty('oauth2.salesforce', JSON.stringify(uProps));
  //Logger.log(nuProps);
}
```

My connected app works, it has the following oAuth2 scopes:

- Perform requests on your behalf at any time
- Access your basic information
- Provide access to your data via the Web
- Access and manage your data

Comment: What do your stackdriver logs look like, and what is the timeout error you are getting?